# JS Object Loop returns undefined, whereas Lodash map returns value

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a loop in JS, and once the loop is complete the value is returning as null, if I use lodash for the same purpose, it returns the result.

This is what I tried:

JS:

```
const jsRows = Object.entries(response).forEach(([key, row]) => {
    return row;
});
console.log(jsRows) ==> Output undefined
```

Lodash:

```
const loRows = map(response, row => {
    return row;
});
console.log(loRows) ==> Output Array
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.forEach()` function *always* returns `undefined`. It is not at all the same thing as a `.map()` function. The native JavaScript `Array.prototype.map()` also returns a new array.

The `.forEach()` function is for "doing something" with each element of an array in a situation where you don't need a new result comprised of a transformation of each array value. The `.map()` function, on the other hand, *is* for transforming an array into a new array based on a transformation of each array element.